# Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`? in a react-dom.development.js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-dom

every since i run my website locally i keep getting this error along with two other errors. The problem is that i do understand the errors but they are pointing to a file called "react-dom.development.js 86" which i dont even have and cant find the following file in my vs code.

Here is a picture of the errors i have been getting in the console:

[image]

This is my pingbutton.js file:-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Pingbutton.scss";
import "./Pingbutton.css";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
// import find_my_iphonen from "./Users/omarfares/Desktop/PINGOMAR/ping-omar-Backend/app.js";
import axios from "axios";

class Pingbutton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { val: "Here is your message omar!:   " };
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
  
    console.log("its running");
    let databody = {
      message: this.state.val,
    };
    console.log(" the message is :" + databody.message);
    console.log(" the message is :" + this.state.val);
    return fetch("http://localhost:5000/stored", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(databody),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  };

  changeval = () => {
    let newval = this.textInput.value;
    console.log("submitted");
    this.setState({ val: newval });
    console.log(this.state.val);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ok2">
        <textarea
          className="message"
          ref={(input) => {
            this.textInput = input;
          }}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Write me somthing!. Also, double click to ping:) "
          // value={this.state.val}
        ></textarea>

        <button
          className="button"
          onClick={() => {
            this.magic();
            this.changeval();
            this.handleSubmit(); //animation + //pinging the phone
            // this.handleButtonClick(); //setVal(() => ""); //sets the value of the box to empty
          }}
        ></button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pingbutton;
```

*im using react js, node js/mac*

Thank you.

Comment: `"react-dom.development.js 86" which i dont even have` That's the file for the react-dom library. The stack trace says the problem is in `Pingbutton`. Can you show us the code for that file?

Comment: yeah sure I will do so.

Comment: Alternatively, just search for `class=`, and change what you find to `className=` (assuming you find it in a react component)

Comment: Thats exactly what i did but as i mentioned in the question I can find that class. Its in react dom library

Comment: React dom is the library that knows how to take your react code and put it onto the dom. The stack trace comes from react dom because when react dom was rendering your component, it noticed a problem with your component. React dom does not render anything that you don't ask it to render.

Comment: The code that you added in doesn't match the stack trace. The stack trace says there should be a `div` surrounding a `body` surrounding an `a`. Maybe search for where the `<body>` element is in your codebase, and hunt around there.

Comment: It's pointing out that body elements are not meant to be inside div elements. Probably switch out the body for something else. Or if you meant to use body, then delete the surrounding divs.

Comment: is there any legal tag that i can wrap my code with while the code includes body and it wont have any affect on the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245598/discussion-between-william-and-nicholas-tower).

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you wrote `class` instead of `className`. To set class in React, use `className`. And also, in the second error it looks like you put the `body` tag in a `div` tag.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question the file doesn't exist so i can make theses changes to it!